# App crash on button click weird issue

Tags: ios, macos-sierra, nsbutton, nsviewcontroller

I create a window in which I take custom view. Here is my [PROJECT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtbty9o3elqow2g/LogoMojis.zip?dl=0).

Credetials : modijecky@gmail.com, Password : 2

Just sign in through credetials and click on second option in side bar and then click on login.

Here my code to add xib view in my viewcontroller of my main view

```
- (IBAction)watchClicked:(id)sender {
    //id animator = [[ContactUsVC alloc] init];
    ContactUsVC* vc = [[ContactUsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactUsVC" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.frame = self.view_main.bounds;

    [self.custom_view addSubview:vc.view];

    [self.view_main setEnabled:NO];

}
```

I put a button on `ContactUsVC` and when I click app crashed. I dont understand why simple click is not happen.

Here is Error

```
Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Description: -[_NSImageAuxiliary btn_click_phone_no:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080002c10a0
User Info: (null)
```

Comment: ceck once your btn_click_phone_no outlet name is correct ot not

Comment: I checked and also remove action method and declare though its not working

Comment: check once in your project entirly

Comment: Yeah, I checked for my mistake but i cant found issue for button click

Comment: Disconnect regarding outlets and work with new outlets.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Does same but nothing changes

Comment: can you attach project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I just attached it

Comment: credentials are modijecky@gmail.com and password is 2

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik 
Just click on second option is side bar and click on login button

Comment: @JitendraModi - sorry bro, i cant figout the issue

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Didn't get issue? I also tried but cant found out issue

Comment: @JitendraModi - give the time i will check omce again

Comment: ok, thank you @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place breakpoint before this line

```
ContactUsVC* vc = [[ContactUsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactUsVC" bundle:nil];
```

And check whether button's action is executed or not.By crash description it seems Image Button. Have you place any image on button?

Comment: Just download my project and solve it. Dont put blind answers.

Comment: Its Done. You have to add just one line.

    ContactUsVC* vc = [[ContactUsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactUsVC" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.view_main.bounds;
    
    [self.custom_view addSubview:vc.view];
    
    [self.view_main setEnabled:NO];

Comment: Add     [self addChildViewController:vc];
Before vc.view.frame = self.view_main.bounds; and its working.

Comment: Yeah ,got it. Works

Comment: Whats my mistake here?

Comment: You have added vc.view in your custom view. So when any action of vc will be performed in its view controller you parent view controller doesn't recognize that.
In order to inform parent view controller, this addChildViewController method is used.

Comment: Ok, its my first time developing mac application so I am not familiar with its methods. Thank you for helping me